# Cat looks wounded, what is wrong with it?

Tags: cats

[image: Stray cat image]

I found this stray cat outside my home with yellowish liquid running down its eyes. I'm not sure if it's pus from an infection or a bad wound from a fight. Tried to  offer it some food but it didn't seem interested.

Does anybody have an idea what's afflicting it? I'd like to know if it is serious and what can I do immediately to help it. Thanks

Comment: you need to bring the cat to a vet,the cat have a serious flea infestation and a serious infection.a feral cat not eating is a serious sign of problems.

Comment: The ONLY thing you can do is take this cat to a vet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely serious, looks like it could be a major infection and there are definite signs of fleas. Bring it to the vet if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This seems serious problem for cat! Because eyes are the most sensitive part of their face. And if the liquid is running down from its eyes rather than any side area (not sure), then its serious issue. You should go to vet as soon as possible. But if it is not possible for you immediately then use some ointment or cream till that.

I can't define or state any sure reason, but it seems like the cat is fall down from some spot.

Hope this will help you.